# Enum type transition constraint

Tags: system-verilog

I'm trying to understand a transition of enum type constraint in SystemVerilog.

I declared 2 enums about direction and size as the below,
and constrained it as long as direction is `READ` and size is `BYTE`, then it randomized.

```
typedef enum { READ, WRITE }                direction_t;  
typedef enum { BYTE, HALFWORD, WORD }       size_t;  
typedef enum { NONE, SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE } delay_t; 
                                 
                                 
class ahb_item ;                 
                                                     
  rand direction_t direction;                        
  rand size_t size_enum;                             
  rand delay_t delay;                                
                                                     
  constraint trans1_c {                              
            (direction == READ) -> (direction==WRITE)-> (direction==WRITE);
    }                                                
                                              
endclass                         
                                 
module top;                      
                                 
ahb_item  item;                  
                                 
initial begin                    
  repeat(10) begin               
  item = new();                  
  if(!item.randomize())          
    $display("ERROR Randomize"); 
  
  $display("prev:%p, current:%p, next:%p, size_enum:%p", item.direction.prev(), item.direction, item.direction.next(), item.size_enum);
  end                            
                                 
end  
                             
endmodule
```

I expected that I could get a constrainted enum value `(direction == READ) -> (direction==WRITE)-> (direction==WRITE)` current value supposed to be a `READ` and next will be a `WRITE` and `WRITE`, but I get the below.  How do I get the constrained value from an enum type?

```
prev:WRITE, current:READ, next:WRITE, size_enum:HALFWORD
prev:WRITE, current:READ, next:WRITE, size_enum:WORD
prev:WRITE, current:READ, next:WRITE, size_enum:HALFWORD
prev:WRITE, current:READ, next:WRITE, size_enum:WORD
prev:WRITE, current:READ, next:WRITE, size_enum:WORD
prev:READ, current:WRITE, next:READ, size_enum:HALFWORD
prev:READ, current:WRITE, next:READ, size_enum:BYTE
prev:WRITE, current:READ, next:WRITE, size_enum:HALFWORD
prev:WRITE, current:READ, next:WRITE, size_enum:HALFWORD
prev:WRITE, current:READ, next:WRITE, size_enum:BYTE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concept of "transition" in randomization.  Perhaps you are thinking of transition coverage.  When you use the enum methods `prev` and `next`, they just return values from the fixed enum list.  If the current `direction` is `WRITE`, then `next` and `prev` will always just return the other enum value (`READ`).  Those methods have no knowledge of what the `direction` variable had prior.

If you always want `direction` to alternate values between calls to `randomize`, you need to do more work.  One way is to store the `direction` value from the previous `randomize` call, then to `randomize` `with` that value on all subsequent calls:

```
typedef enum { READ, WRITE }                direction_t;
typedef enum { BYTE, HALFWORD, WORD }       size_t;
typedef enum { NONE, SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE } delay_t;

class ahb_item ;
    rand direction_t  direction;
    rand size_t       size_enum;
    rand delay_t      delay;
endclass

module top;

ahb_item item;
direction_t dir;

initial begin
    item = new();
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) begin
        if (i==0) begin
            if (!item.randomize()) $display("ERROR Randomize");
        end else begin
            if (!item.randomize() with {direction==dir;}) $display("ERROR Randomize");
        end
        $display("direction:%p, size_enum:%p", item.direction, item.size_enum);
        dir = item.direction.prev();
    end
end

endmodule
```

Output:

```
direction:READ, size_enum:HALFWORD
direction:WRITE, size_enum:HALFWORD
direction:READ, size_enum:BYTE
direction:WRITE, size_enum:WORD
direction:READ, size_enum:BYTE
direction:WRITE, size_enum:BYTE
direction:READ, size_enum:BYTE
direction:WRITE, size_enum:WORD
direction:READ, size_enum:HALFWORD
direction:WRITE, size_enum:WORD
```